# do web.config changes get deployed in .dll?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to deploy changes to my web application. On my localhost I made changes to the web.config file. I do not have much experience in deployment to other servers.. and noticed the team deployed the app but the web.config file appears unchanged.

Do the web.config changes get compiled into the \bin*.dll files or does the web.config file ALWAYS need to get updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web.config is a separate protected text file that needs to be separate on the server in the application's root directory. It does not get compiled into the .dll. If you update a web.config file on the server, it will cause the application to recycle to load the new values.

Answer (score 1):

No.  web.config files are not compiled.

If you modify your local web.config you should deploy the new version to your servers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719558(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

web.config changes does not compiled in dll files or bin folder. you should upload web.config.